# Removing frameworks from Xcode project now that they are being managed by Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, git, github, cocoapods

I just added `Cocoapods` to my xcode project. I followed all of the instructions, and all of my frameworks were installed perfectly. However, now I have duplicates. I have frameworks in my `Pods` directory, and these same frameworks are still in my project's `Frameworks` group.

What would be the proper way to go about removing these duplicates? Should I remove them from the `Frameworks` group? Should I remove the `Frameworks` group altogether?

If I do remove them, how can I properly link to the new ones in the `Pods` directory so that the compiler knows where their new location is?

Also, if I do remove the duplicates, will this create conflicts when trying to commit these changes to my project's GitHub repo?